# TypeError: d.getTime is not a function. (In 'd.getTime()', 'd.getTime' is undefined) only in production environment

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, date

I was creating simple clock for my app. with this piece of code:

```
<div id="clock" class="nav-item dropdown">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var d = new Date({!! time() * 1000  !!});

    function digitalClock()
    {
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + 1000);
        var hrs = d.getHours();
        var mins = d.getMinutes();
        var secs = d.getSeconds();
        mins = (mins < 10 ? "0" : "") + mins;
        secs = (secs < 10 ? "0" : "") + secs;
        hrs = (hrs < 10 ? "0" : "") + hrs;
        var ctime = hrs + ":" + mins + ":" + secs;
        document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = "<b>"+ ctime +'</b>&nbsp;';
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        digitalClock();
        setInterval('digitalClock()', 1000);
    }
</script>
```

every thing is working perfectly on my local environment, but for reason i cannot understand in production environment I'm getting this error.

> TypeError: d.getTime is not a function. (In 'd.getTime()', 'd.getTime' is undefined)

I was thinking that php is not loading time correctly but in code it looks good. Any idea?

Comment: {!! time() * 1000  !!} this is laravel call for time function. It is calling time() when blade template is loading. In Standard it would look like <?php echo time() * 1000; ?>

Comment: woops, sorry, didn't see it

Comment: What do you see if you log d from inside the digitalClock function in the development and production environments?

Comment: Ok, guys. Sorted out. Thanks for pointing me in right direction @KarlGraham when I logged data, I found out out when laravel blade template is loaded d variable is overwritten, so I renamed it and it is working.

Comment: Try logging the value of `d` in your function to find out what it is. `console.log(d);`

Comment: Note that this clock will drift, since *setInterval* doesn't run at **exactly** 1,000ms but you are adding exactly 1,000ms to the Date.

Comment: Where is *time* defined? What is the value of `{!! time() * 1000  !!}` when evaluated? Seems to me it'a a syntax error.

Comment: @RobG thanks for info, I know it is not exactly 1000ms, this is only informative, because sometimes it happening that server time is little different than local machine time and all data and forms generated by laravel contains timestamp from server.
`{!! time() * 1000 !!}` is generating time based on php function [time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)